# bootstrap-datetimepicker takes client system time, how to set default time from server

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap-datepicker "bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" I want to run this plugin depending on server date and time.

```
var d1 = new Date (),
d2 = new Date ( d1 );
d3 = new Date ( d1 );
d2.setMinutes ( d1.getMinutes() + 10 );
$(window).load(function(){
$(".scheduledatetime").datetimepicker({format: 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii', 
autoclose : "true", startDate:d2,minuteStep:15 ,endDate: '+10d'});
});
```

Comment: use ajax and bring date from server !

Comment: @bRIMOs did the same , still not getting. Can you shed some more light on this

Answer (score 0):

simple solution in Javascript

Get a UTC time and then add `offset` to it as per your server timezone

here is offset is difference with UTC time and server time(in seconds)

```js
var offset = 0;
var now = new Date(); 
var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
var sd = new Date(now_utc.getTime() + offset);
alert("The Server time is " + sd.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: Thanks. If its works please mark it as an answer so that others can get benefit from it